# Gambler's ruin stopping time: can't understand the connection between the general and a specific solution

Tags: probability, gambling

In Shiryaev's probability book, in page 87, it is given that

> Taking account of $(8),$ we find that for 
>   $A \leq x \leq B$ $$
>  \beta(x)=\frac{(q / p)^{x}-(q / p)^{A}}{(q / p)^{B}-(q / p)^{A}}$$
>
> [...]
>
> If $p=q=\frac{1}{2},$ the only solutions $\beta(x)$ and
>   $\alpha(x)$ of (7),(8) and (11),(12) are respectively $$
>  \beta(x)=\frac{x-A}{B-A} $$

However, if we put $p=q=0.5$ into the first equation, we simply get $(1-1)/(1-1)$, which is undefined, so **I can't understand how does the author get the second equation from the first one.**

Comment: To understand your question, it would be helpful if you can list equations "(7), (8), (11), (12)" here. I believe it is not a simple substitution of $p = 0.5$ and $q = 0.5$ to the general formula but a special treatment is needed.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t^x-t^A}{t^B-t^A}=\frac{x-A}{B-A}$ by L'Hosptial's Rule.